# Onclick method cannot be found. Trying to launch mobile network settings

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to launch the mobile network settings screen in android 4.1 with a button click. On the button click I am getting "Could not find a method onOKclicked(View) in the activity class." My code is below. Any help would be appreciated!

```
public void onOKclicked (Intent intent){
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NETWORK_OPERATOR_SETTINGS), 0);
    startActivity(intent);
}

<activity android:name="android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NETWORK_OPERATOR_SETTINGS"></activity>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOK"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/OkButton" 
    android:onClick="onOKclicked" />
```

Comment: As the answers explain, if you use the `android:onClick` attribute in a layout file, the method form must be `public void methodName(View v)`

Comment: Also, why are you calling `startActivityForResult(...)` AND `startActivity(...)`? Only one activity can be visible / active at any time.

Comment: Im new to java/android. Looks like I needed to take off startActivity. Thanks. Now I am not launching into the correct network settings page. It is going to available networks and not mobile network settings. Any suggestions? edit: nm needed to change to .ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is looking for a function named `onOKclicked` with a `View` as parameter (the button)

```
public void onOKclicked (View v){
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NETWORK_OPERATOR_SETTINGS), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your method to say `public void onOKclicked (View view)` instead.  It's looking for a method where the `view` is passed in, not the `intent`.

Comment: Then on startActivity(intent) I get intent cannot be resolved to a variable and if I change intent to view i still get errors

Comment: I just deleted the second activity. Thanks!